# Unsupported operation: Cannot modify an unmodifiable list

Tags: flutter, dart, zip, archive

I need help.
I'm trying to extract files from an archive.

```
var byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/res.zip');
      var buffer = byteData.buffer;
      var archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(buffer.asUint8List(),
          verify: true, password: '123');

      for (final file in archive) {
        final filename = file.name;
        if (file.isFile) {
          final data = file.content as List<int>;
          File('$tempPath/files/$filename')
            ..createSync(recursive: true)
            ..writeAsBytesSync(data);
        } else {
          Directory('$tempPath/files/$filename').create(recursive: true);
        }
      }
```

But I'm getting this error..................

```
E/flutter ( 8813): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot modify an unmodifiable list
E/flutter ( 8813): #0      _UnmodifiableUint8ArrayView.[]= (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:5391:5)
E/flutter ( 8813): #1      ZipFile._decodeZipCrypto (package:archive/src/zip/zip_file.dart:192:12)
E/flutter ( 8813): #2      ZipFile.content (package:archive/src/zip/zip_file.dart:129:27)
E/flutter ( 8813): #3      ZipDecoder.decodeBuffer (package:archive/src/zip_decoder.dart:32:41)
E/flutter ( 8813): #4      ZipDecoder.decodeBytes (package:archive/src/zip_decoder.dart:16:12)
E/flutter ( 8813): #5      _HomePageState.dataWriteToLocal (package:mytest/Pages/home_page.dart:417:36)
E/flutter ( 8813): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: The error is getting occurred after you call the 'ZipCoder().decodeBuffer()' function. (Understood from Call Stack). Please provide that function also

Answer (score 0):

`buffer.asUint8List()` is not modifiable. You can make it modifiable by converting it to a normal list:

```
var archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(buffer.asUint8List().toList(),
          verify: true, password: '123');
```